# jQuery.noConflict() is it working? Load multiple jquery files on the same page

Tags: jquery, html

Although there are many solutions provided even here at stackoverflow, none of them seems to work. I've found many people complaining about this on the net. How to load 2 different jquery files on the same page? Or some workaround this. To me, it is working only the one that is the last called on the page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jq162 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

I tried this also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      (function(){

        var myBkl = {
                 jq: null,
                 loadScript: function(src) {
                        if(window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn.jquery == '1.6.2'){
                                return;
                        }
                        var s = document.createElement('script');
                        s.setAttribute('src', src);
                        s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s); 
                },
                whenLoaded: function(callback){
                        if (typeof(window.jQuery) !== 'undefined' && window.jQuery.fn.jquery == '1.6.2') { 
                                myBkl.jq = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
                                callback(myBkl.jq); 
                        } 
                        else {
                                setTimeout((function() {myBkl.whenLoaded(callback); }), 100);
                        } 
                },
                init: function($){
                        console.log($.fn.jquery);
                        console.log(window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
                }
        };
        myBkl.loadScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js');
        myBkl.whenLoaded(myBkl.init);

})();
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me... jQuery 1.6.2 is accessed via `jq162` and jQuery 1.5.1 is accessed thru `jq151` and `jQuery`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need 2 different versions of jQuery in the first place?

I'm pretty sure you can make everything work with 1.6.2 (given some very little changes like prop()... )